# Is it possible to transfer sip incoming call (remote address) to the another app like another sip client apps?

Tags: android, kotlin, sip, incoming-call

If it is possible how to do I am developing sip client in android studio in kotlin for android using linphone sdk.

Thanks in Advance.

Do anyone have solution for this please share I am working on this from a long time.